# How to convert all numbers into math mode

Tags: tables, math-mode

I have a table converted from excel. I want to transform the numbers in the table to the math mode, i.e.,     15  ->  $15$.  Is there any visual way I can use it.
I am using TexStudio.

CODE:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Comparison of microaggregation algorithms to protect different datasets for $k=\{3,4,\ldots,10\}$}
    \begin{tabular}{cr|rrrrrrrrc}
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Dataset} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{Method}} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Information Loss (\%)}                     & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Elapsed time (sec)} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & $k=3$   & $k=4$   & $k=5$   & $k=6$   & $k=7$   & $k=8$   & $k=9$   & $k=10$  &  \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[1]{*}{\dataset{Tarragona}}  & KD-CBFS & 16.9500 & 19.7700 & 22.8900 & 26.4100 & 28.2600 & 29.3100 & 31.6200 & 33.2600 & $<1$ \\
          & V-MDAV & 16.9507 & 19.7695 & 22.8867 & 26.4131 & 28.2616 & 29.3119 & 31.6184 & 33.2601 & $<1$ \\
          & FDM   & 15.8548 & 17.8439 & 22.6442 & 25.1970 & 27.7465 & 28.9472 & 30.0313 & 32.8549 & $<1$ \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Census}} & KD-CBFS & 5.6620 & 7.5140 & 9.0070 & 10.3654 & 11.6688 & 12.3068 & 13.3368 & 14.0730 & $<1$ \\
          & V-MDAV & 5.6620 & 7.5140 & 9.0070 & 10.3654 & 11.6688 & 12.3068 & 13.3368 & 14.0730 & $<1$ \\ 
          & FDM   & 5.3828 & 7.0645 & 8.7178 & 10.1436 & 11.3940 & 12.6727 & 13.7732 & 14.7735 & $<1$ \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{EIA}} & KD-CBFS & 0.4883 & 0.6727 & 1.7764 & 1.3157 & 2.2141 & 2.9910 & 3.4086 & 3.5474 & $<1$ \\
          & V-MDAV & 0.4884 & 0.6718 & 1.7693 & 1.3157 & 2.2081 & 2.9917 & 3.4086 & 3.5474 & $1$ \\ 
          & FDM   & 0.4808 & 0.7311 & 1.0678 & 1.3533 & 1.7343 & 1.9019 & 2.0491 & 2.1674 & $<1$ \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Income}} & KD-CBFS & 0.675015 & 0.928399 & 1.19127 & 1.4107 & 1.58581 & 1.80879 & 1.94347 & 2.12738 & $1$ \\ 
          & V-MDAV & 0.655816 & 0.928362 & 1.19121 & 1.41074 & 1.58681 & 1.80878 & 1.94346 & 2.12738 & $90$ \\
          & FDM   & 0.593726 & 0.838746 & 1.0747 & 1.30892 & 1.5398 & 1.75383 & 1.95588 & 2.15949 & $1$ \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Forest}} & KD-CBFS & 0.494946 & 0.703865 & 0.885494 & 1.05023 & 1.20079 & 1.33881 & 1.46986 & 1.59104 & $67$ \\
          & V-MDAV &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & $>3600$ \\
          & FDM   & 0.426531 & 0.608566 & 0.782772 & 0.952619 & 1.11867 & 1.28177 & 1.44231 & 1.59784 & $65$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:results1}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Use the “Align Column” function of TeXstudio and then block select right before the first column of numbers and add `$` where you need it. *Or:* Change the column specifications to `>{$}r<{$}` (and remove the `$` in the header and/or use `\multicolumn`). *Or:* Use `siunitx`.

Comment: You will need to `\usepackage{array}` to enable the `>{$}r<{$}` mark up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the [`siunitx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/siunitx) package for this table, which avoids the issue.

You'll notice that I have used `S[table-format=2.5]` to mean that there are at most `2` numbers *before* the decimal, and `5` numbers *after* it.

[image: screenshot]

I wasn't sure what the `dataset` command was supposed to do- you'll need to change it appropriately.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\dataset}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison of microaggregation algorithms to protect different datasets for $k=\{3,4,\ldots,10\}$}
    \begin{tabular}{cr|S[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-comparator=true]}
        \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Dataset} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[1]{*}{Method}} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Information Loss (\%)}                     & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Elapsed time (sec)} \\
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & {$k=3$}  & {$k=4$}  & {$k=5$}  & {$k=6$}  & {$k=7$} & {$k=8$} & {$k=9$}   & {$k=10$}  &         \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}[1]{*}{\dataset{Tarragona}} & KD-CBFS               & 16.9500  & 19.7700  & 22.8900  & 26.4100  & 28.2600 & 29.3100 & 31.6200 & 33.2600 & <1    \\
                                                & V-MDAV                & 16.9507  & 19.7695  & 22.8867  & 26.4131  & 28.2616 & 29.3119 & 31.6184 & 33.2601 & <1    \\
                                                & FDM                   & 15.8548  & 17.8439  & 22.6442  & 25.1970  & 27.7465 & 28.9472 & 30.0313 & 32.8549 & <1    \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Census}}    & KD-CBFS               & 5.6620   & 7.5140   & 9.0070   & 10.3654  & 11.6688 & 12.3068 & 13.3368 & 14.0730 & <1    \\
                                                & V-MDAV                & 5.6620   & 7.5140   & 9.0070   & 10.3654  & 11.6688 & 12.3068 & 13.3368 & 14.0730 & <1    \\ 
                                                & FDM                   & 5.3828   & 7.0645   & 8.7178   & 10.1436  & 11.3940 & 12.6727 & 13.7732 & 14.7735 & <1    \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{EIA}}       & KD-CBFS               & 0.4883   & 0.6727   & 1.7764   & 1.3157   & 2.2141  & 2.9910  & 3.4086  & 3.5474  & <1    \\
                                                & V-MDAV                & 0.4884   & 0.6718   & 1.7693   & 1.3157   & 2.2081  & 2.9917  & 3.4086  & 3.5474  & 1     \\ 
                                                & FDM                   & 0.4808   & 0.7311   & 1.0678   & 1.3533   & 1.7343  & 1.9019  & 2.0491  & 2.1674  & <1    \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Income}}    & KD-CBFS               & 0.675015 & 0.928399 & 1.19127  & 1.4107   & 1.58581 & 1.80879 & 1.94347 & 2.12738 & 1     \\ 
                                                & V-MDAV                & 0.655816 & 0.928362 & 1.19121  & 1.41074  & 1.58681 & 1.80878 & 1.94346 & 2.12738 & 90    \\
                                                & FDM                   & 0.593726 & 0.838746 & 1.0747   & 1.30892  & 1.5398  & 1.75383 & 1.95588 & 2.15949 & 1     \\ \hline
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Forest}}    & KD-CBFS               & 0.494946 & 0.703865 & 0.885494 & 1.05023  & 1.20079 & 1.33881 & 1.46986 & 1.59104 & 67    \\
                                                & V-MDAV                &          &          &          &          &         &         &         &         & >3600 \\
                                                & FDM                   & 0.426531 & 0.608566 & 0.782772 & 0.952619 & 1.11867 & 1.28177 & 1.44231 & 1.59784 & 65    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:results1}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

And just for comparison, here's an option using the `booktabs` package

[image: booktabs screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\dataset}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Comparison of microaggregation algorithms to protect different datasets for $k=\{3,4,\ldots,10\}$}
    \begin{tabular}{crS[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.6]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-format=2.5]S[table-comparator=true]}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Dataset} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Method} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Information Loss (\%)}                     & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Elapsed time (sec)} \\
                                                &         & {$k=3$}  & {$k=4$}  & {$k=5$}  & {$k=6$}  & {$k=7$} & {$k=8$} & {$k=9$} & {$k=10$} &       \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}[1]{*}{\dataset{Tarragona}} & KD-CBFS & 16.9500  & 19.7700  & 22.8900  & 26.4100  & 28.2600 & 29.3100 & 31.6200 & 33.2600  & <1    \\
                                                & V-MDAV  & 16.9507  & 19.7695  & 22.8867  & 26.4131  & 28.2616 & 29.3119 & 31.6184 & 33.2601  & <1    \\
                                                & FDM     & 15.8548  & 17.8439  & 22.6442  & 25.1970  & 27.7465 & 28.9472 & 30.0313 & 32.8549  & <1    \\ 
        \cmidrule{3-11}
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Census}}    & KD-CBFS & 5.6620   & 7.5140   & 9.0070   & 10.3654  & 11.6688 & 12.3068 & 13.3368 & 14.0730  & <1    \\
                                                & V-MDAV  & 5.6620   & 7.5140   & 9.0070   & 10.3654  & 11.6688 & 12.3068 & 13.3368 & 14.0730  & <1    \\ 
                                                & FDM     & 5.3828   & 7.0645   & 8.7178   & 10.1436  & 11.3940 & 12.6727 & 13.7732 & 14.7735  & <1    \\ 
        \cmidrule{3-11}
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{EIA}}       & KD-CBFS & 0.4883   & 0.6727   & 1.7764   & 1.3157   & 2.2141  & 2.9910  & 3.4086  & 3.5474   & <1    \\
                                                & V-MDAV  & 0.4884   & 0.6718   & 1.7693   & 1.3157   & 2.2081  & 2.9917  & 3.4086  & 3.5474   & 1     \\ 
                                                & FDM     & 0.4808   & 0.7311   & 1.0678   & 1.3533   & 1.7343  & 1.9019  & 2.0491  & 2.1674   & <1    \\ 
        \cmidrule{3-11}
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Income}}    & KD-CBFS & 0.675015 & 0.928399 & 1.19127  & 1.4107   & 1.58581 & 1.80879 & 1.94347 & 2.12738  & 1     \\ 
                                                & V-MDAV  & 0.655816 & 0.928362 & 1.19121  & 1.41074  & 1.58681 & 1.80878 & 1.94346 & 2.12738  & 90    \\
                                                & FDM     & 0.593726 & 0.838746 & 1.0747   & 1.30892  & 1.5398  & 1.75383 & 1.95588 & 2.15949  & 1     \\ 
        \cmidrule{3-11}
        \multirow{3}[0]{*}{\dataset{Forest}}    & KD-CBFS & 0.494946 & 0.703865 & 0.885494 & 1.05023  & 1.20079 & 1.33881 & 1.46986 & 1.59104  & 67    \\
                                                & V-MDAV  &          &          &          &          &         &         &         &          & >3600 \\
                                                & FDM     & 0.426531 & 0.608566 & 0.782772 & 0.952619 & 1.11867 & 1.28177 & 1.44231 & 1.59784  & 65    \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tab:results1}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `siunitx` in the last column too with: `S[table-format=<4.0]` (or `table-comparator=true`). The fourth `S` column needs `table-format=2.6` because of the last row (`0.952619`).